# type '_internalLinkedHashMap<String,dynamic> is not a subtype of type list <dynamic> error in flutter. Below is my code,im a beginner

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<List<Data>> fetchData() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
      'http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=can&y=2018&type=movie&apikey=9f4f767e'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    List jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);

    return jsonResponse.map((data) => new Data.fromJson(data)).toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception('Unexpected error occured!');
  }
}

class Data {
  late String title;
  late int year;
  late int imdbID;
  late String type;

  Data(
      {required this.title,
      required this.year,
      required this.imdbID,
      required this.type});

  Data.fromJsonN(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    title = json['title'];
    year = json['year'];
    imdbID = json['imdbID'];
  }

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Data(
      title: json['title'],
      year: json['year'],
      imdbID: json['imdbID'],
      type: json['type'],
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future<List<Data>> futureData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    futureData = fetchData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter movie API and ListView Example',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Flutter movie ListView'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<List<Data>>(
            future: futureData,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                List<Data>? data = snapshot.data;
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Container(
                        height: 75,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(data[index].title),
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("${snapshot.error}");
              }
              // By default show a loading spinner.
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that problem to set jsonResponse as List dynamic

```
List<Data> dataResponseModel = (jsonResponse['data'] as List<dynamic>)
              .map((data) => Data.fromJson(data))
              .toList();


return dataResponseModel;
```

Comment: Could you please show me where I should add this line. When I tried it its showing error

Comment: if (response.statusCode == 200) you can use it under that if and configure to your code what you want to use for. Json has map in it. You should find what name is where your data stores in json. Diwyansh's answer what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is that you are passing **Map<String, dynamic>** where you have to pass a **List**. When you decode your `json` string it gives you a `Map` like :

```
{
 Search : [{You data}]
}
```

But you need the a `List` then you have to select search that will return you a `list` so make a little `change` to your code like below :

```
List jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body)["Search"];
```